# Android: refreshing a listview from a 'grandchild' activity

Tags: android, android-activity, refresh

I have a setup as follows

> Activity 1 uses a ListView and ListAdapters to display information
>   from list of objects of type A (by retrieving from the database the first time its called).
>
> Upon clicking an item in the ListView in Activity 1, the control goes
>   to Activity 2, which again uses a ListView and ListAdapters to display
>   information from list of objects of type B.
>
> There is a '+' button in Activity 2, which when tapped switches the
>   control to Activity 3. Here I can create an object of type B and save it to the database.
>   Now I use the `setResult()` in Activity 3 and `onActivityResult()` in Activity 2 to update the list in Activity 2.

So far so good. I can see the item of type B that I just created in Activity 2.

> Now if I press the back button and go back to Activity 1, and tap on
>   the same item of type A then when I go to the Activity 2, the item that I had just created
>   does not show. However when I close the app, and open it again, and
>   follow the same path, I can see that item. (As the list was reloaded from the database)
>
> So how do I update the list in Activity 1?

I hope I explained my question properly (apologize if not!). I don't want to put all the code here, since there is no issue with the code, unless my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code which loads the list from database in `Activity.onResume()` method. This way it should execute every time your activity is restored from invisible state (take a look at [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) on activity lifecycle for more info).

Also, you might want to implement loading from database using [`Loader`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html). It monitors the data source for updates, thus keeping data up to date.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. So I can put the new object in the `onStop()` in Activity 2 and get it in the `onResume()` in Activity 1 and update the list. I will try it!

Comment: @rgamber if you mean "put the object into database in the `onStop()`", then yes, that's the way.

Comment: So I now use a `Loader` along with a `ContentProvider` for database operations, and have added the code which loads the list from database in the `Activity.onResume()`, and that solves my problem. But I am still not sure that this is the best way to do it. Basically I am now making a trip to the database and reloading the full list to just load/update one new item. I couldn't find how to use the `LoaderManager` in the activity to avoid doing the database trip. May be I will comeback to this question!